# An Arraylist of a Generic class

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

i want to access generic objects from a list but always get an incompatible typs error message.

```
MyGenericContainer <Cursor> cursorContainer = new MyGenericContainer<Cursor>(c);
ArrayList <MyGenericContainer> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyGenericContainer>();
arrayList.add(cursorContainer);
Cursor cursor = arrayList.get(0).getValue();
```

In generally is there a way to put generic objects to a list and get access to every single one (without cast)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `ArrayList` typed with a *raw* `MyGenericContainer`. Thus, the compiler implies that the `ArrayList` will consist of `MyGenericContainer` of `Object` instances.

In order to fix it, you need to set the type-parameter of the `MyGenericContainer` type:

```
List<MyGenericContainer<Cursor>> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyGenericContainer<Cursor>>();
```

If you're on Java7+, then you could take advantage of the diamond (`<>`), which will allow you type a less verbose declaration:

```
List<MyGenericContainer<Cursor>> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: I guess you might want to add that he can use the diamond operator; and that there is no need to repeat the the type information.

Comment: Thanks, @Jägermeister, I will.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I generally I want to put objects from different classes in my list, like: `new ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.add(new String());
arrayList.add(new Integer());
int a = arrayList.get(1); //needs to be cast`

This workaround i want to resolve with generics (without cast).

Comment: If you want to put objects of different types, then you have to do a cast, since the compiler cannot be aware of what objects will you put at Runtime.

Comment: @logerom you can want it, but it doesn't make that possible.  You will have to do casts, or even better, write your own class with properly typed fields instead of abusing ArrayList like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Aren't you missing something while creating your arraylist ?

Change it like this and should work fine, I suppose :

```
ArrayList <MyGenericContainer<Cursor>> arrayList = new ArrayList<MyGenericContainer<Cursor>>();
```